# Link value not updating after 'Save'

Tags: navigation

I've got a content type that has a [link field](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) in it. I added this link: '
https://wwwdev.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/' and saved. Then I realised this was an old address. It should have been 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/' so I went back in, added the new address, and saved again. But the value didn't change! It was still showing 'https://wwwdev.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/'. Here's what I've done:

- Flushed the Drupal caches
- Flushed the browser cache
- Tried in a new private/incognito window in another browser
- Checked the database - it has the correct value, not the one showing on the page
- Tried another url in the link field (like 'www.google.com') and that works fine
- I put the correct address back in the field and it shows as the wrong address, even though the wrong address doesn't exist in the database.
- Tried adding the correct address to the body field and it was transformed to the wrong address!
- In 'Manage display' I tried the different settings for the link field. 'Domain as link' resulted in the right domain showing in the link text  ('www.ebi.ac.uk') but with the link 'https://wwwdev.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/' in the `href` attribute.

Does anyone know what might be happening? I'm not using Conditional Fields, incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed this. It was a legacy script in html.tpl.php. What I should have tried in my debugging was to switch theme. That would have at least narrowed it down to the theme layer.